# Soft delete on table

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

I just started using soft delete and I am not really sure how to do it, I am just following someone example and is still unsure how to do a proper soft delete. All I want is to delete the personal_info table but I keep on getting a no error message which make me at lost since I don't know what I am doing wrong, can someone help me? Thanks a lot

home.blade.php

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><strong><big>Name: </big></strong></th>
        <th><strong><big>Action </big></strong></th>
      </tr>
      <td>
      <tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
      <tr>    
      <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
      <th><form action="{{  url('/home/'.$value->id.'/delete')  }}" method="post">
        <button>Delete</button>
      </form></th>               
      </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Controller:

```
public function delete($id = 0){   
    if ($id > 0){
        personal_info::destroy($id);
    }
    return redirect("/home");
}
```

or should I do it this way?

```
public function delete($id){
$data = personal_info::find($id)->delete();
    return redirect("/home");
}
```

personal_info model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Eloquent;
use SoftDeletes;
class personal_info extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('Name');
    protected $table = 'personal_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
        public function user_info1s() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\user_info1','user_id');
    }
```

Route: (not sure should I use DELETE instead)

```
Route::get('/home/{id}/delete', 'HomeController@delete');
```

[image]

Comment: Using soft deletes, would work with a timestamp, so basically soft deleting a database record, you would give that specific records 'deleted_at' field a timestamp, and then when you loop your data out in the frontend, you would adjust your query with something like 'where delete_at === NULL'

Comment: But how do I give a timestamp, in the resources that I follow, all I did was just do this, "$table->softDeletes();" @WesMurray

Comment: I also just used the where clause "personal_info::findOrFail($id)->where('deleted_at', '=', NULL)->delete();" and it deleted all my data.. @WesMurray

Comment: I fail to understand why you user.show as a `<a>` and then delete as a form... Why not have both as a `<a>` and then the route would be `Route::get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use delete on the method. try to change your function to this

```
public function delete($id){   
    personal_info::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    return back();
}
```

> Edit

The Route method and Form method must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Route::get('/home/{id}/delete', 'HomeController@delete');
```

To

```
Route::post('/home/{id}/delete', 'HomeController@delete');
```

Controller Method

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

public function delete($id)
{
  personal_info::find($id)->update([
      'deleted_at' => Carbon::now()
  ]);

  return redirect()->back();
}
```

home.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><strong><big>Name: </big></strong></th>
        <th><strong><big>Action </big></strong></th>
      </tr>
      <td>
      <tr>

        // Example of adjusting your query to support soft deletes
        @php
          $data = Some\Model::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->get();
        @endphp

        @foreach($data as $value)
      <tr>    
      <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
      <th><form action="{{  url('/home/'.$value->id.'/delete')  }}" method="post">
        <button>Delete</button>
      </form></th>               
      </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: could you explain what is this "use Carbon\Carbon;"?

Comment: or is that just an example that you have used?

Comment: A simple PHP API extension for DateTime.

Comment: enabled carbon in your controller with 'use Carbon\Carbon' then using the Carbon::now() with allocate a timestamp

Comment: $data = Some\Model::where('deleted_at', NULL)->get(); for this part do I need to put in?

Comment: And also Some\Model, for this I just replace with my model?

Comment: Some\Model = Your Model Path\Name. Example App\User

Comment: Only use carbon in the deleted method

Comment: Ok but $data = Some\Model::where('deleted_at', NULL)->get();  is just coming out as text, shouldn't I put something like {{  }}?

Comment: Ok nvm, I add in the php tag inside

Comment: The button isn't redirecting me, are we missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157650/discussion-between-wes-murray-and-blastme).

Comment: sorry just came back, we continue in chat? @WesMurray

Comment: I found out why it is not working, it because of use SoftDeletes; I put at the wrong place thanks to Onix for pointing out my mistake, Thanks for your help also :)